# TYPO 7.6 Display Content

Tags: html, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

Hey im trying to implant an HTML template but i cant get the content displayed working..

```
  ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
//
// Subpart CONTENTMIDDLE
//
////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

CONTENTMIDDLE = CONTENT
// Middle column (labeled "normal")
CONTENTMIDDLE < styles.content.get
```

}`

### Middle Column - Element 1

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
                vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet.

### Middle Column - Element 2

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr,
                sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et
                dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero
                eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem
                ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
                sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut
                labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
                vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet
                clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum
                dolor sit amet.

```
    </div>`
```

Comment: Please provide more information:

- Where is the code you posted at?
- how are your files looking (Template, Typoscript) and how are they called inside TYPO3 (Typoscript, etc.)?
- What exactly works and what does not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`styles.content.get` is defined either from CSC or FSC (and you need to include the static templates).
In FSC there was one version where the definition was done to late for usage in other typoscript, so you may need to define it by yourself, which you also need to use if you use none of these rendering definitions:

```
styles.content.get = CONTENT
styles.content.get {
     table = tt_content
     select {
         orderBy = sorting
         where = colPos=0
     }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using "styles.content.get" and that is used if you have enabled css_style_content extension, otherwise please use the below code.

```
CONTENTMIDDLE = CONTENT
CONTENTMIDDLE.table = tt_content
CONTENTMIDDLE.select.pidInList = TSFE:id
```